# flash texts - how to make it so you cant click text in-game?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a static text in flash, however I can click it and highlight it.

Is there a way to make it so it acts like a plain movieclip object?

Comment: TextFields have a `selectable` property. You can either set it through code, or simply set it in Flash itself when you have the Textfield selected. It should be near the other settings for textfields, like color, font size etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable propagation of any `MouseEvents`:

```
textfield.mouseEnabled = false;
```

And/ or disable the `selectable`-property:

```
textfield.selectable= false
```

Comment: I found another way, click the selectable button and disable it.